# Roots of $x^p + x + [\alpha]_p \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $$g(x) = x^p + x + [\alpha]_p \in \mathbb{F}_p[x],$$ where $p$ is prime.

> For which $\alpha, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ does $g(x)$ have *at least*
> one root? And for which $\alpha, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ does $g(x)$
> have *exactly*  one root?

Supposing that $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a root of $g(x)$, then, by *Euler's Theorem* (or *Fermat's Little Theorem*), I get that it is a root of $$h(x) = 2x + [\alpha]_p.$$ So we can say that for $p=2$ we have two roots (that is $0,1$) if $\alpha \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and no root if $\alpha \equiv 1 \mod 2$. *What can we conclude for the other cases?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, by Euler we have $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$ for all $x\in\Bbb{Z}_p$, so
$$x^p+x+[\alpha]_p\equiv 2x+[\alpha]_p,$$
holds for all $x\in\Bbb{Z}_p$. So if $p\neq2$ then $x=-\tfrac{1}{2}[\alpha]_p$ is a root, and it is in fact the only root.

Comment: As suggested, this works *for all* $\alpha\in\Bbb{Z}$ if $p\neq2$.

Comment: Oh. Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$\gcd(x^p+x+\alpha,x^p-x)=\gcd(2x+\alpha,x^p-x),$$
where $\gcd$ denotes the greatest common divisor in $\mathbb Z_p$. Observe that, if the degree of the gcdis positive, then it is equal to the number of distinct roots of $g(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_p$.

We have two cases:

1. If $p\neq 2$ then $$\gcd(2x+\alpha,x^p-x)=x+2^{-1}\alpha,$$ and $-2^{-1}\alpha$ is the unique root in $\mathbb Z_p$, for every $\alpha$.
2. If $p=2$, then you already have the solution.

Comment: if $p\neq 2$ $g(x)$ has exactly one root for every $\alpha$